# JQuery load functions on AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a field on a form, that when it's filled it calls an ajax call.

The ajax call fills the other fields of the form fine and everything.

But I've got some functions on them fields and they are only working after I click on those fields..

```
$('#lista').on('keypress keydown keyup change',function(){
    var qtd_itens = $('#lista tbody').children('tr').length + 1;
    somatotal = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < qtd_itens; $i++) {
        acho = new String($(':input[name="qtd' + $i + '"]').val()),
    alto = new String($(':input[name="preco' + $i + '"]').val());
    acho = acho.replace(',', '.');
    alto = alto.replace('.', '');
    alto = alto.replace(',', '.');
        v = 0;

        if (!isNaN(acho) && !isNaN(alto)){
            v = parseFloat(acho*alto,2);
        }
        $(':input[name="total' + $i + '"]').val(formatter.format(v));
    somatotal += v;
    $(':input[name="valortotal"]').val(formatter.format(somatotal));
    }
});
```

I know this is happening because I am using the on('keypress keydown keyup change' event. But, is there a way that when the ajax call is called this already does the job without me clicking on the fields?

Comment: It is not clear what problem you're asking about.  Are you loading content with ajax and then finding that event handlers aren't working on the new content?  Or something else?

Comment: they are actually working.. but i need to click on the fields for them to format the numbers, because i'm using on click event. i wanted that when im loading the content with ajax they already do the job without me clicking on it.

Comment: Using onclick event for what?  There's no code in your question that has anything to do with the onclick event.

Comment: sorry, i meant on keypress keydown keyup change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change event does not fire when you programmatically change a field.  If you want your code to run after you've programmatically filled the fields from your ajax call, then you will have to put your code into a function and call it on those fields AFTER you put new data in them from the ajax call.

For example, you can change your code to this:

```
$('#lista').on('keypress keydown keyup change', itemsModified);

function itemsModified(){
    var qtd_itens = $('#lista tbody').children('tr').length + 1;
    somatotal = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < qtd_itens; $i++) {
        acho = new String($(':input[name="qtd' + $i + '"]').val()),
        alto = new String($(':input[name="preco' + $i + '"]').val());
        acho = acho.replace(',', '.');
        alto = alto.replace('.', '');
        alto = alto.replace(',', '.');
        v = 0;

        if (!isNaN(acho) && !isNaN(alto)){
            v = parseFloat(acho*alto,2);
        }
        $(':input[name="total' + $i + '"]').val(formatter.format(v));
        somatotal += v;
        $(':input[name="valortotal"]').val(formatter.format(somatotal));
    }
)
```

And, then call `itemsModified()` manually after your AJAX call fills the fields.

---

I haven't tried this myself, but you may also be able to leave the code the way you originally had it and after your ajax call fills in the new values, call:

```
$('#lista').trigger("change");
```

This will manually trigger a change event and cause your change handler to do the formatting.

Comment: can you give an example? its already a function.. but how would i call the function after they are filled?

Comment: @GilbertoGonçalvesMachado - FYI, it sure looks like a number of the variables in your function need to have `var` in front of them so they are local variables and not implicit global variables.

Comment: i used the trigger thing and it worked.. thanks a lot